# How to add a column of labels to the right of a plot

Tags: r, layout, plot

I have code producing a swell plot in R. Check it out!

[image: A swell plot in R]

I made it using this code:

```
SwellPlot <- function(Data,P) {
  par(mfcol=c(1,1), mar=c(4, 4.5, 0, 0) + 0.1)
  plot(c(0.5,P+0.5), c(-0.5,P+0.5), type="n", cex=1, lab=c(20,20,1), cex.lab=1.5, yaxs="i", xaxs="i", xlab=~bold("Stuff!"), ylab=~bold("Other stuff!"))
  for (f in 1:(P+1)) {
      for (r in 0:P) {
          points(r,(f-1), pch=15, cex=(60/P)*sqrt(Data[f,r]/200))
          }
      }
  }
```

With `Data` input as a matrix, like this one used for the above example:

```
Data <- matrix(c(0, 117, 76, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 199, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 200, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 188, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 90, 
109, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 38, 143, 19, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 18, 142, 39, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 114, 75, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 95, 99, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 68, 121, 7, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 65, 122, 10, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 65, 
120, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
2, 42, 132, 23, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 35, 135, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 44, 128, 27, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 33, 139, 27, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), 17, 16, byrow=FALSE)
```

I would like to glom a vertical series of labels along the right side of my swell plot (these labels are different than the y-axis labels, which I need to remain as they already are). I have done so by extending the x-axis and using text(), but when I do this it looks kludgy (on the x-axis labels) and because I have plots with quite variable x-axis lengths I have to spend a lot of trial and error time making sure that the width of my labels does not overlap the right-most plotted elements. The improved plot would look kinda like this:

[image: Mock-up of an even sweller plot!]

I *imagine* that there must be some relatively straightforward way of doing this using `layout()` or `mfcol` or somesuch, but the documentation and examples get rapidly complex for me. How would you solve this?

Bonus points for answers that permit me to specifically (1) make the width of the label column I would like to add 8% of the width of my swell plot, and (2) make my swell plot (not including the labels up the right side) retain its 1:1 aspect ratio.

Also bonus points if this can be done using `par` and `plot` and the like.

Comment: You need to share you code to generate the plot above. Also include sample data to reproduce the plot so we can test it. You haven't made it clear which plotting system you are using so it's impossible to make specific recommendations. Can you make an image showing what would like the final product to be? You can just draw on the current plot using Paint or something.

Comment: @MrFlick I hope I have successfully integrated the improvements you requested. If I can do more, let me know. I hope you will consider revising your down-vote following my improvements.

Comment: @RichardScriven You can add a bounty ;)

Comment: Can you help me understand why you suggest using `structure()` and what the `L` suffixes mean in the revision?

Comment: @RichardScriven In colloquial English the phrase "bonus points for ..." means something along the lines of "extra kudos to you if you can go above and beyond the basic request". To answer more directly: "In more gratitude." :)

Comment: @Alexis I reformatted your data because there was no easy way to copy and paste that into R (if it's easier to get the data into R, it's easier to help). I reshaped the data and read it into R with read.table and converted to matrix. Then i dumped the results with `dput`. Since internally the values are stored as integers, the `dput` added the `L` which means an integer literal as opposed to a general numeric value. Your edit is just as helpful. It's better to post data that way from the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possibility. You can either add `rownames` to your `Data` or you can pass in a vector of names

```
SwellPlot <- function(Data,P=nrow(Data), labels=!is.null(rownames(Data))) {
  par(mfcol=c(1,1), mar=c(4, 4.5, 0, 3) + 0.1)
  plot(c(0.5,P+0.5), c(-0.5,P+0.5), 
      type="n", cex=1, lab=c(20,20,1), 
      cex.lab=1.5, yaxs="i", xaxs="i", 
      xlab=~bold("Stuff!"), ylab=~bold("Other stuff!")
  )
  cex<-(60/P)*sqrt(Data/200)
  points(col(Data), row(Data), pch=15, cex=cex)
  if(is.logical(labels) && labels) {
    labels = rownames(Data)
  }
  if(is.character(labels)) {
    axis(4, labels=labels, at=1:P, las=1, tick=F)
  }
} 

#add names for labeling
lbl<-c("",rev(c("Ant","Bat","Cat","Dog","Eel","Fly","Gar","Hog")), rep("",8))
rownames(Data)<-lbl
SwellPlot(Data)
```

[image: swell plot]

I just drew the extra names with `axis` and I made sure to make room for them by adjusting the `par`

I also edited the middle to take out the two loops. Those were pretty slow. You can do it all with one call to points passing all the x,y pairs at once. The trick is that if you pass a data.frame, it will convert it to a simple vector. So if all the matrices are arranges the same way, you'll get a point for each cell.